# How to merge two activity which extend different classes?

Tags: java, android, extends

I want to merge two different activity into one activity to merge view.

For example, I have activity A and activity B. I want to merge two activity in same view. But the problem is they are extending other classes. activity A extends ActionBarActivity and activity B extends other custom Activity. Extending 2 classes is not allowed. So I can't merge two activity to one.

how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use fragments instead of activities. With fragments you can separate different part of your page with different views in one activity.

[About fragments](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_fragments.htm)

Comment: I tried to use fragment. but to use fragment, It should extends Fragment. So I can't extend my custom class

Comment: @shj each fragment has it's own layout. Fragments are like mini-activities.for every fragment: Make a class, extend fragment, on onCreateView method inflate your costume view, use it in your main activity.

Comment: yes. but activity which uses fragment should write 'extends Fragment' , doesn't it? I need to extend my custom class in fragment. but it can't because java don't support multiple inheritance.. Am I misunderstood something?

Comment: You can have one class that extends activity , and one,two or more class that extend fragment. You should use your costum fragments classes into your main activity .